# Using Async/Await with Pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-3.5

I am new to `async`/`await`, and I came across a bit of confusion. Should `pickle` be `await`ed somehow?

For example, say I have the following `async` class methods:

```py
async def get(self, key):
    redis = await self.getRedis()
    data = await redis.get(key)
    if not data:
        return None

    return pickle.loads(data)

async def set(self, key, value, ttlInSeconds):
    pickled = pickle.dumps(value)

    redis = await self.getRedis()
    await redis.setex(key, pickled, ttlInSeconds)
```

If I'm serializing or unserializing a large object, won't the entire loop block on `pickle`? For practical purposes, with smaller objects, is this momentary blocking acceptable? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You *should block* on pickling because if another method in your class could then execute and modify `value` while `set()` is still processing `pickle.dumps()`, the pickled data will be corrupt.

This applies even if that object will definitely only ever have one instance at a time.

Btw in `get()`, you could put `await` for `return pickle.loads(data)` since you're not likely to modify data that hasn't been returned out of that method yet.

Comment: I see, thanks! I guess I took the "all or nothing" advice about async a bit too seriously. I was under the impression that you needed to `run_in_executor()` all blocking code.